# DDOS mod Rewrite IP Request

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ddos

We're receiving a DDOS attack from a specific range of IPs (192.168.0-255.0-255). In our htaccess file we've attempted to forward their requests to a static HTML file but only half the requests are being blocked. Does anyone see why that would be?

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(10\.0\.0\.1|192\.168\.[0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{0,3})$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/etc/blocked_ip.html]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /etc/blocked_ip.html [R=301,L]
```

and our access logs show:

```
2014-06-27 11:59:03 192.168.20.232 - 1.2.3.4 443 GET /etc/blocked_ip.html ?
2014-06-27 11:59:08 192.168.20.231 - 1.2.3.4 443 GET /video/832
```

Note: I've substituted the actual IP ranges with private ranges.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Just a question from one that isn't versed in these things: aren't IPs around `192.168` usually local?

Comment: Yes, they're private, I substituted the actual ranges.

Comment: @anubhava that is the access log you are looking at. The first IP is the requesting IP, the second is the servers address so it's not needed.

Comment: We ended up modifying the iptables to accomplish the blocking.

    iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255 -j DROP

This isn't the answer but an alternative for other users that encounter this same issue. (I also can't mark this as an answer because I'm a new user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your rewrite condition is incorrect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/etc/blocked_ip.html]
```

Probably you meant:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/etc/blocked_ip\.html
```

You rule can be shortened to:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(10\.0\.0\.1|192\.168\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})$
RewriteRule !^etc/blocked_ip\.html$ /etc/blocked_ip.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Also make sure this is your very first rule in your .htaccess.

Comment: The rewrite worked to stop the loop if the user was already on the page they were directed to

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/etc/blocked_ip.html]

The issue was that they weren't being directed to that page all the time; probably about 65% of the time.

Comment: I'm not sure that solution worked. I know the rewrite condition we had in place wasn't incorrect as it worked correctly (stopped after the first rewrite to the blocked page) for us in the office (we blocked our internal access to confirm first). The issue was why aren't about 35% of their requests being rewritten. This was the first rule in our htaccess. Moving this over to the IP tables did the trick.